# Redirigir a URL desde input HTML

Tags: html, css, django, diseño

Tengo el siguiente codigo en HTML

```
<form class="w3-center w3-padding-16" method="get" action="" >
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Buscar en {{categoria}}" autofocus required>
    <input type="submit">                            
</form>
```

Cuando pongo algo en la busqueda se me añade "?=TEXTO_BUSCADO" y yo quiero que me redirija a un href tal que asi "example.com/TEXTO_BUSCADO"

Comment: ¿Puedes usar _javascript_? Con HTML no se va a poder

Comment: No habria problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar Javascript, de manera que prevenimos que el formulario se envíe y obtenemos el valor del *input*, finalmente redirigimos a la página

```js
sendToUrlForm.addEventListener("submit", e => { // Escuchar cuando se envíe el formulario
  const sendUrl = "https://ejemplo.com"; // Url a redirigir
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir que se envíe
  location.href = sendUrl+"/"+sendToUrlForm.querySelector("[name=q]").value;
  // Será reenviado a "ejemplo.com/VALOR_DEL_INPUT"
});
```

```html
<form class="w3-center w3-padding-16" id="sendToUrlForm" method="get" action="" >
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Buscar en {{categoria}}" autofocus required>
    <input type="submit">                            
</form>
```

Usaremos [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para obtener un elemento dentro del *form*

Si el *form* cambia de *id*, es importante cambiarlo en el código JS también

En este caso, le he puesto `id="sendToUrlForm"`, por lo tanto, para referirnos a el *form*, usamos `sendToUrlForm` en Javascript

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion, muchisimas gracias ;)